# autocomplete jquery does not return expected results

Tags: php, jquery

I am developing a simple jquery autocomplete using php. It works just fine for the most part... but when I do certain searches, it does not detect specific entries. For example, when I search for "Si" I get a list including "Simon", but when I search for "Jo" there is nothing.

Here are the two files I have:

1. index.php

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Search</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /> 
   </head>
   <body> 

   <form action='' method='post'>
   <p><label>Name:</label><input type='text' name='Name' value='' class='auto'></p>
   </form>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {

   //autocomplete
   $(".auto").autocomplete({
   source: "search.php",
   minLength: 2
           });             
           });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. search.php

   ```
   <?php

   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
   define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
   if (isset($_GET['term'])){
   $return_arr = array();
   try {
       $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

       $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Name FROM People WHERE Name LIKE :term');
       $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

       while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
           $return_arr[] =  $row['Name'];
       }
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }
   /* Return results as json encoded array. */
   echo json_encode($return_arr);
   } 
   ?>
   ```

Might this have something to do with an exception list? Or have I made an error with the code?

As a newbie I am in awe of the great help from this site!

Comment: Does you ```search.php``` returning anything when you are searching with ```Jo``` ?

Comment: Does your table has entries, in which Name starts with `Jo`?